# How to add more than one function in user-extension.js - Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am very new to Selenium IDE or javascript and was using google to learn it and do some testing of my website application. In my application I need to input user name and date of activity as part of the testcase.

I used random string generator function I saw online and created a user-extension.js to be called in S-IDE for the user name and was using a storeEval command to generate a date 5 days from today's date to give in the date of activity field. But today being 26th of Apr, when I run the script it is generating a date of 31-Apr which is invalid date and the test is failing.

I again found some code snippets online on how to check if the date generated is valid and then pass valid date back. But when I append this to the user-extension.js (Selenium.prototype.doValidDay) that I am having, this function is not recognized by S-IDE more over my random string function is also not recognized. (Meaning I am not able to find the command when I type on the command line of S-IDE)

Can someone please help me understand how to append multiple commands in a userextension js? I even created 2 js and selected both of them in options tab. Still not working..

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This for getting future date.

Selenium.prototype.doTypeTodaysDate = function(locator){
var dates = new Date();
dates.setDate(dates.getDate() + 5);
var day = dates.getDate();
if (day < 10){
day = '0' + day;
}

month = dates.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10){
month = '0' + month;
}
var year = dates.getFullYear();
var prettyDay = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
this.doType(locator, prettyDay);
}

Copy the above code into note pad and save as date.js

after that add the date.js file into selenium ide  

Options->Selenium core Extensions->browse the file

Think it will work for you.

Thank you
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Thanks a lot for the code. I am already having a js selected in the options > Selenium core Extension section. So when I select date.js as well I am not able to get the command TypeTodaysDate in the command line... I have restarted FF and opened S-IDE fresh after selecting the extension js. But it is still not working. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Since its not working you do one thing uninstall your selenium plugin and install new version selenium ide 2.0.0 and try  once more.